# How to make div cover the whole page when scrollbar exist?

Tags: html, css

```
    <div id="outer_product_wrapper" style="display: none;">
        <div id="outer_inner_product_wrapper">
            <div id="inner_product_wrapper">
                Test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want a div that fills the whole page with a black overlay. How can I achieve this with css?
I have tried using position fixed on the outer_product_wrapper, but then I lose the scrollbar...

```
#outer_product_wrapper{
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
        }

#outer_inner_product_wrapper{
   ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : it is best to use the trick top:0/bottom:0 than height:100%

I don't know if it solves your problem but it can be a clue ;)

```
#outer_product_wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, and doesnt solve the problem.. I need the overlay to fill the whole page and not only what you see when the page is loaded..

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Overflow property of CSS3

overflow-x: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|no-display|no-content;

If you want that div to be scrollable  of x-axis
then overflow-x : scroll;

and if you dont want then overflow-y : hidden;

```
#content
{
width:300px;
height:400px;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#outer_product_wrapper
{    
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.85;
}
```